# Identity OAuth implementation with Owin

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvc, oauth, owin

I am building an MVC 5 application using code-first Entity Framework 6 and a customised ASP.NET Identity model for authentication.

I will only be authenticating against external OAuth providers (Google, Facebook etc) and persisting the login and claims information in custom code-first EF entities.

Since this is the first time I have worked with the ASP.NET Identity model and Owin, I want to make sure I haven't made any major errors in the code I have so far, which does work and registers a new user, saves their claims and persists their login using a cookie.

I will try to keep the code as small as possible while still showing all relevant details. I am using AutoFac for dependency injection.

**User.cs** - Implementation of `IdentityUser`

```
public class User : IdentityUser<string, UserLogin, UserRole, UserClaim>
{
    public User()
    {
        // without this Id would be NULL when I create a new User
        base.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    }

    public User(string userName)
        : this()
    {
        base.UserName = userName;
    }

    .... other properties
}
```

**UserLogin**, **UserRole** and **UserClaim** are simply classes that implement their relevant `IdentityUserX` base class.

**DbContext.cs** - Standard DbContext implementing `IdentityDbContext` with above classes

```
public class DbContext : IdentityDbContext<User, Role, string, UserLogin, UserRole, UserClaim>
{}
```

**UserService.cs** - Implementation of UserStore

```
public class UserService : UserStore<User, Role, string, UserLogin, UserRole, UserClaim>
{}
```

**RoleService.cs** - Implementation of RoleStore

```
public class RoleService : RoleStore<Role, string, UserRole>
{}
```

**ApplicationClaimsIdentityFactory.cs** - reimplementation of ClaimsIdentityFactory. Needed because I was getting duplicate claims added because the Name and NameIdentifier claims are saved into the database, and re-added at sign in.

```
public class ApplicationClaimsIdentityFactory : ClaimsIdentityFactory<User, string>
{
    // identical to normal ClaimsIdentityFactory until:
        if (manager.SupportsUserClaim)
        {
            var userClaims = await manager.GetClaimsAsync(user.Id).WithCurrentCulture();
            foreach (var userClaim in userClaims)
            {
                if (!id.HasClaim(userClaim.Type, userClaim.Value))
                {
                    id.AddClaim(userClaim);
                }
            }
        }
        return id;
    }
}
```

**ApplicationUserManager.cs** - Implementation of UserManager specifying to use custom ClaimsIdentityFactory

```
public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<User, string>
{
    public ApplicationUserManager(UserStore<User, Role, string, UserLogin, UserRole, UserClaim> store) : base(store)
    {
        this.ClaimsIdentityFactory = new ApplicationClaimsIdentityFactory();
    }

    public static ApplicationUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager>options, IOwinContext context)
    {
        var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserService(context.Get<DbContext>()));
        return manager;
    }
}
```

**ApplicationSignInManager.cs** - Implementation of SignInManager with new entities

```
public class ApplicationSignInManager: SignInManager<User, string>
{
    public ApplicationSignInManager(ApplicationUserManager userManager, IAuthenticationManager authManager)
        : base(userManager, authManager)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationSignInManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationSignInManager> options, IOwinContext context)
    {
        return new ApplicationSignInManager(context.GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>(), context.Authentication);
    }
}
```

**Startup.Auth.cs**

```
public partial class Startup
{
    static Startup()
    {
        PublicClientId = "self";
        ExternalAuthPageUrl = "Account/ExternalAuthRequestCallback";
        var applicationOAuthProvider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId, ExternalAuthPageUrl);
        OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        {
            Provider = applicationOAuthProvider,
            RefreshTokenProvider = applicationOAuthProvider,
            AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/Account/ExternalLogin"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(30),
            AllowInsecureHttp = false
        };
    }

    public static OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthOptions { get; private set; }
    public static string PublicClientId { get; private set; }
    public static string ExternalAuthPageUrl { get; private set; }

    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {            
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, User>(
                                        validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15),
                                        regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
            },
            SlidingExpiration = true,
            ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30)
        });

        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

        app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);

        var authOptions = new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions();
        authOptions.ClientId = "OAuthKey";
        authOptions.ClientSecret = "OAuthSecret";
        authOptions.Scope.Add("email");

        app.UseGoogleAuthentication(authOptions);
    }
}
```

**AccountController.cs**

```
[AllowAnonymous]
// displays a list of available external authenticators for the user to pick
public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl = "/")
{
    IEnumerable<AuthenticationDescription> descriptions = Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.GetExternalAuthenticationTypes();
    IList<ExternalProviderViewModel> providers = new List<ExternalProviderViewModel>();

    foreach (AuthenticationDescription description in descriptions)
    {
        ExternalProviderViewModel model = new ExternalProviderViewModel
        {
            Url = Url.Action("ExternalLogin", new
            {
                provider = description.AuthenticationType,
                response_type = "token",
                client_id = Startup.PublicClientId,
                redirect_uri = new Uri(Request.Url, returnUrl).AbsoluteUri + Startup.ExternalAuthPageUrl
            })
        };

        providers.Add(model);
    }
    return View(providers);
}

// Once a user picks a provider
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult ExternalLogin(string provider, string error = null)
{
    return new ChallengeResult(loginProvider.Name, Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback", "Account"));
}

// On return from provider
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
{
    var loginInfo = await _authManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
    if (loginInfo == null)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Login");
    }

    // Sign in the user with this external login provider if the user already has a login
    var result = await _signInManager.ExternalSignInAsync(loginInfo, true);
    switch (result)
    {
        case SignInStatus.Success:
            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
            return View("Lockout");
        default:
            // If the user does not have an account, then prompt the user to create an account
            ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
            ViewBag.LoginProvider = loginInfo.Login.LoginProvider;
            return View("ExternalLoginConfirmation", new ExternalLoginConfirmationViewModel { Email = loginInfo.Email });
    }
}

// The External Login Confirmation view just confirms the user's email address, then submits to:

[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginConfirmation(ExternalLoginConfirmationViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Get the information about the user from the external login provider
        var info = await _authManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
        var user = new User { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
        var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            result = await _userManager.AddLoginAsync(user.Id, info.Login);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, true, true);
                ExternalLoginModel externalLogin = ExternalLoginModel.FromIdentity( info);
                OwinHelper.SignIn(Request.GetOwinContext(), user, externalLogin, _userManager);

                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }
        }
    }
    ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
    return View(model);
}
```

**OwinHelper.cs**

```
public static class OwinHelper
{
    public static void SignIn(IOwinContext owinContext, User user, ExternalLoginModel externalLogin, ApplicationUserManager userManager)
    {
        owinContext.Authentication.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
        var oAuthIdentity = CreateIdentity(user, OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        var cookieIdentity = CreateIdentity(user, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        SaveClaims(oAuthIdentity, user, userManager);
        var properties = CreateProperties(user);
        owinContext.Authentication.SignIn(properties, oAuthIdentity, cookieIdentity);
    }

    private static ClaimsIdentity CreateIdentity(User user, string authenticationType)
    {
        IList<Claim> claims = new List<Claim>();

        claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Id, null, ClaimsIdentity.DefaultIssuer, "Provider"));
        claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.FullName, null, ClaimsIdentity.DefaultIssuer, "Provider"));
        claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, user.Email, null, ClaimsIdentity.DefaultIssuer, "Provider"));
        claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.GivenName, user.FullName, null, ClaimsIdentity.DefaultIssuer, "Provider"));

        return new ClaimsIdentity(claims, authenticationType);
    }

    private static void SaveClaims(ClaimsIdentity identity, User user, ApplicationUserManager userManager)
    {
        foreach (var claim in identity.Claims)
        {
            if (identity.HasClaim(claim.Type, claim.Value))
            {
                userManager.RemoveClaim(user.Id, claim);
            }
            userManager.AddClaim(user.Id, claim);
        }
    }

    public static AuthenticationProperties CreateProperties(User user)
    {
        IDictionary<string, string> data = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "email", user.Email },
            { "name", user.FirstName ?? string.Empty }
        };
        return new AuthenticationProperties(data);
    }
}
```

I think that's everything that's relevant. Like I said, I'm looking for a review of my Identity and OAuth implementation, not general code quality. I've removed a lot of Null checks and alike to try and shorten the code a bit.

Please let me know if there's something you feel I might have missed, and any comments on my code I'm happy to receive.

Answer (score 4):

A static class named `OwinHelper`, with methods `SignIn`, `CreateIdentity` and `CreateProperty`, and `SaveClaims`, smells funny. "Helper" is a bad sign all by itself ("Manager" is also a sign), `static` is another bad sign, and the public members are a bad sign: the class has all the characteristics of a type with already too many responsibilities, that will scale by [growing hair and tentacles](http://www.meupapeldeparedegratis.net/fantasy/pages/cthulhu-rises.asp).

These static "helper" methods probably belong as private members / implementation details of the types they're "helping".

> ```
> public static AuthenticationProperties CreateProperties(User user)
> {
>     IDictionary<string, string> data = new Dictionary<string, string>
>     {
>         { "email", user.Email },
>         { "name", user.FirstName ?? string.Empty }
>     };
>     return new AuthenticationProperties(data);
> }
> ```

Consider these members as part of the `User` class:

```
private readonly Lazy<AuthenticationProperties> _authProperties;
public AuthenticationProperties AuthProperties { get { return _authProperties.Value; } }
```

I'm assuming the members you stripped from your post are `private readonly` and only ever assigned from the constructor: if the `User` type isn't immutable then you have another problem. Anyway the idea is to create that `Lazy<T>` in the constructor when you're receiving the `Email` and `FirstName`, and because *your user is immutable* you don't need to worry about whether these values are going to change by the time the `AuthProperties` are needed, so you can just cache an instance.

---

This method:

> ```
> private static ClaimsIdentity CreateIdentity(User user, string authenticationType)
> {
>     IList<Claim> claims = new List<Claim>();
>
>     claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Id, null, ClaimsIdentity.DefaultIssuer, "Provider"));
>     claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.FullName, null, ClaimsIdentity.DefaultIssuer, "Provider"));
>     claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, user.Email, null, ClaimsIdentity.DefaultIssuer, "Provider"));
>     claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.GivenName, user.FullName, null, ClaimsIdentity.DefaultIssuer, "Provider"));
>
>     return new ClaimsIdentity(claims, authenticationType);
> }
> ```

Could be simplified to this:

```
private static ClaimsIdentity CreateIdentity(User user, string authenticationType)
{
    var claims = new List<Claim>
    {
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Id, null, ClaimsIdentity.DefaultIssuer, "Provider"),
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.FullName, null, ClaimsIdentity.DefaultIssuer, "Provider"),
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, user.Email, null, ClaimsIdentity.DefaultIssuer, "Provider"),
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.GivenName, user.FullName, null, ClaimsIdentity.DefaultIssuer, "Provider")
    };

    return new ClaimsIdentity(claims, authenticationType);
}
```

That's a *collection initializer syntax* calling `.Add` under the hood for you... but you know that, since you're using it to initialize a `Dictionary` a few lines further...

Notice I used `var` here, because <s>I use it everywhere, `var` is awesome!</s> it's obvious what the type is.

I find it ironic that you wouldn't specify `var` here:

> ```
> IDictionary<string, string> data = new Dictionary<string, string>
> ```

Or here:

> ```
> IList<Claim> claims = new List<Claim>();
> ```

But that you would do it here:

> ```
> var oAuthIdentity = CreateIdentity(user, OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType);
> var cookieIdentity = CreateIdentity(user, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
> var properties = CreateProperties(user);
> ```

Or even here:

> ```
> foreach (var claim in identity.Claims)
> ```

Don't get me wrong: I *love* `var` and I really <s>ab</s>use it a lot. I can live with a codebase that doesn't use it *everywhere*, but in a codebase that uses it sparingly, I like to see consistency, and I expect to see it where it's useful (i.e. when the type is redundant boilerplate clutter) - not where the type isn't obvious from the statement itself!